# Regular expression that matches with a group of numbers

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've multiples lines with this text:

```
insert into table1(IDEORGVENSUB, IDEORGSUB, IDEVENDEDOR, IDEORGVEN_SUP, FECINI, FECFIN, STSACTIVO, USUCREACION, FECCREACION, FECMODIF, USUMODIF, IDEFAMILIA, IDEPRODFAMILIA, IDETIPANTICIPO, VALANTICIPO, STSCADUCO)
values (3960, 302, 6572, 3246, to_date('01-01-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), null, 1, 'MCMSMCMS', to_date('01-01-2001', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('01-01-2001', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'MCMSMCMS', null, null, null, null, 0, 302, 'ASESOR X', 115, 234, 1, 'MCMSMCMS', to_date('01-01-2001', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), null, to_date('01-01-2001', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'MCMSMCMS', 47, 3, 1);
```

The final text should be this:

```
insert into table1 (IDEORGVENSUB, IDEORGSUB, IDEVENDEDOR, IDEORGVEN_SUP, FECINI, FECFIN, STSACTIVO, USUCREACION, FECCREACION, FECMODIF, USUMODIF, IDEFAMILIA, IDEPRODFAMILIA, IDETIPANTICIPO, VALANTICIPO, STSCADUCO)
values (3960, 302, 6572, 3246, to_date('01-01-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), null, 1, 'MCMSMCMS', to_date('01-01-2001', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('01-01-2001', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'MCMSMCMS', null, null, null, null, 0);
```

I need replace this part (The number 302 changes) by ');' for get final text:

```
, 302, 'ASESOR X', 115, 234, 1, 'MCMSMCMS', to_date('01-01-2001', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), null, to_date('01-01-2001', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'MCMSMCMS', 47, 3, 1);
```

I'm using this regular expression in the Notepad++ for replace with caracters ");" and get the final text but don't work...

```
, [268|269|270|271|272|273|274|275|276|277|291|293|296|299|301|302|303|305|266|267|308|309|310|185|186|231|232|233|235|236|237|238|239|279|280|184|265|278|281|282|283|284|285|286|287|288|289|290|292|294|295|297|298|300|304|234|240|241|242|307|312|264|311|313], '+[\w ',()-:]*;$
```

I've used this another regular expression, but only work for one number:

```
, 265, '+[\w ',()-:]*;$
```

Help me please

Comment: What is the rule in words? Try `,\h+\d{3},\h+'+[\w\h',():-]*;$`

Comment: Only should be replace this text ", 302, 'ASESOR X', 115, 234, 1, 'MCMSMCMS', to_date('01-01-2001', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), null, to_date('01-01-2001', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'MCMSMCMS', 47, 3, 1);" by ");". 302 number changes in another lines. This regular expression don't work: , 265, '+[\w ',()-:]*;$. Instead of 265 number shoul be used an expression that matches with a group of numbers.

Comment: Ok, can you match the text you want to replace with `,\h+\d{3},\h+'+[\w\h',():-]*;$`? I can in my Notepad++. Or does it have to be the range you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change your pattern from brackets (character class inregex) to parentheses allowing the grouping of possible alternatives:

`, (268|269|270|271|272|273|274|275|276|277|291|293|296|299|301|302|303|305|266|267|308|309|310|185|186|231|232|233|235|236|237|238|239|279|280|184|265|278|281|282|283|284|285|286|287|288|289|290|292|294|295|297|298|300|304|234|240|241|242|307|312|264|311|313), '+[\w ',()-:]*;$`

[image]

<s>It could be simplified more by formulating ranges. Coming...</s>

Finally by grouping those valid numbers in ranges (in an easy to read way):

`, (18[4-6]|23[1-9]|24[0-2]|26[4-9]|2[7-9][0-9]|30[0-9]|31[0-3]), '+[\w ',()-:]*;$`

Comment: Works fine in notepad, are you sure you have the last version (If i'm not wrong, older ones had some troubles)...

Comment: @CesarCasasola Also, can you please post the valid ranges for that variable number to simplify the pattern; so far I noticed `184-186; 231-242; ...`

Comment: The ranges should matches with numbers that I've posted

Comment: This regular expression work fine. I've had an older version.

Answer (score 1):

The `[...]` construct is called a *character class* that matches a *single character* from the specified set (even `|` are considered a literal pipe in them). You meant to use a *grouping* construct, that is, `(...)` or a non-capturing variant `(?:...)`.

To replace the substring you need with `);` you may use the following regex:

```
,\h+\d{3},\h+'+[\w\h',():-]*;$
```

Or - if you need to preserve your ranges -

```
,\h+(?:18[456]|23[1-9]|24[0-2]|26[4-9]|27[0-9]|28[0-9]|29[0-9]|30[0-57-9]|31[0-3]),\h+'+[\w\h',():-]*;$
```

And use `\);` as a replacement pattern.

Note that a regular space in a Notepad++ regex pattern can be replaced with a `\h` (a horizontal space). I contracted your ranges a bit. Also, the **`)` must be escaped** in the replacement pattern since it has a special meaning in a Boost conditional replacement pattern.

[image]